# adaPerUTxOWord not found on testnet-shelley-genesis.json

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-node

Run cardano-node 1.27.0 testnet error, adaPerUTxOWord not found on testnet-shelley-genesis.json

```
cardano-node  run --database-path ~/cnode-testnet/db --socket-path ~/cnode-testnet/sockets/node.socket --port 3001 --config ~/cnode-testnet/config/testnet-config.json  --topology ~/cnode-testnet/config/testnet-topology.json
    
    
    Error decoding genesis at: /home/qi.mou/cnode-testnet/config/testnet-shelley-genesis.json Error: Error in $: key "adaPerUTxOWord" not found

    cardano-node --version
    cardano-node 1.27.0 - linux-x86_64 - ghc-8.10
    git rev 17096c3fe7a52264906ff92ed245ded2344b3d00
```

after I add "adaPerUTxOWord":0 to testnet-shelley-genesis.json, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you paste the output of `cardano-node --version`?

Comment: cardano-node 1.27.0 - linux-x86_64 - ghc-8.10
git rev 17096c3fe7a52264906ff92ed245ded2344b3d00

Comment: It looks like you may be building the master branch, try checking out tag 1.27.0, `cabal clean` and then rebuild. The correct git rev for 1.27.0 is 8fe46140a52810b6ca456be01d652ca08fe730bf

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the config files over at https://hydra.iohk.io/job/Cardano/cardano-node/cardano-deployment/latest-finished/download/1/index.html is a bit behind some of the pre-alonzo work in 1.27.0.

Per discussions over at https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/issues/2725, the *-shelley-genesis.json should now have these additional values:

```
{
  ...
  "securityParam": 2160,
  "adaPerUTxOWord": 0,
  "executionPrices": {
    "prMem": 1,
    "prSteps": 1
  },
  "maxTxExUnits": {
    "exUnitsMem": 1,
    "exUnitsSteps": 1
  },
  "maxBlockExUnits": {
    "exUnitsMem": 1,
    "exUnitsSteps": 1
  },
  "maxValueSize": 1000,
  "costModel": "example/shelley/alonzo/costmodel.json",
  "collateralPercentage": 100,
  "maxCollateralInputs": 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you download official genesis file [from the build system of cardano-node](https://hydra.iohk.io/job/Cardano/cardano-node/cardano-deployment/latest-finished/download/1/index.html).

Comment: Looking at the official configurations, "adaPerUTxOWord" exists on the mainnet version of shelleyGenesis, but not on the testnet, as the question points out.

Comment: I download genesis file from official website, but adaPerUTxOWord not exists on the testnet file.